# Calculate $\frac{\pi}{2}-\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})+\sin(\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}))-\sin(\sin(\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})))\cdots$

Tags: real-analysis, summation, nested-radicals

I would like to calculate following sum:
$$\frac{\pi}{2}-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+\sin\left(\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)-\sin\left(\sin\left(\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)\right)+\cdots\approx1.02$$
It can be rigorously defined as follows:
$$f_n=\sin(f_{n-1})$$
$$f_0=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(-1)^n$$
The sum converges rather slowly. Approximating with $5 \cdot 10^6$ terms gives result $1.020\pm0.0002$
Thanks for all the help

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Do you want to prove that the sum converges? Or do you want to prove that the sum is $1.02\pm \varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon$ that you would need to provide? Or do you want its exact value?

Comment: I want to calculate exact value of this sum.

Comment: I don't think that's doable.

Comment: [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) code `(f(n)=if(n<=0,Pi/2,sin(f(n-1))));sumalt(n=0,(-1)^n*f(n))` returns result $1.0201362070364214421787731549740277318$. You can easily get more digits if you want them.